# echo list of array from column database table

Tags: php, arrays, echo

I am trying to echo a list of all rows from column `userid` and separate them by comma and remove the last comma from the last value

```
    $sql_userid = "SELECT `userid` FROM `tabe_users`";
        $result_userid = $con->query($sql_userid);
        if ($result_userid->num_rows > 0) {
           while($row_userid = $result_push->fetch_assoc()) {
           $getallids = mysqli_free_result($result_userid) . ', ';
           $listallids = substr($getallids, 0, -2);
      }
    }

echo $listallids;
```

Comment: SELECT group_concat(`userid`) as listallids FROM `tabe_users`

Answer (score 0):

Update your code with this, you can't print array in echo, if you want to print in echo than you have to encode your array to json while use it decode again.

or simply use **print_r()**

```
$sql_userid = "SELECT `userid` FROM `tabe_users`";
    $result_userid = $con->query($sql_userid);
    $listallids = array();
    if ($result_userid->num_rows > 0) {
       while($row_userid = $result_push->fetch_assoc()) {
       $getallids = mysqli_free_result($result_userid) . ', ';
       $listallids[] = substr($getallids, 0, -2);
  }
}

echo json_encode($listallids);
// or
print_r($listallids);
```